# VirtualBox6, Ubuntu 18.04LTS very slow, despite good resources

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, virtualization

I set up an 18.04.2 LTS Ubuntu in VirtualBox version 6.0.10 r132072 (Qt5.6.3), and it is horribly slow. It feels like the refresh rate is around 2-3Hz somewhere.

8 logical CPU cores, 100% execution cap, 16GB RAM, PIIX3 chipset, 128MB video memory, 3D acceleration enabled on VBoxVGA, default paravirtualization interface.

[image]

Running on Mac OS X 10.14.5 host, 32GB RAM, i9-9880HQ 8-core hyperthreading, Radeon 560X.

Anyone with any idea on how to speed it up?
( I probably made a simple mistake somewhere, so shoot the most basic answers first )

Comment: You've given your VM too many resources. Back down the CPU to 2, and RAM to 2048.

Comment: That did not help, possibly even felt worse.

Comment: Try turning off 3D. Try 2D or no accel.

Comment: Didn't help yet, but I did read some things that the resolution of the retina screen might be the problem.  Sounded like a VirtualBox issue

Comment: Did you install Guest Additions? If not, then that's your problem. My first comment is still accurate though.

Comment: Guest Additions are installed, and I have the same VM running on a different host with the same resources with no problem.  The heavy resources are kind of nice if the VM is doing heavy calculations.

Comment: The problem with allocating 8 CPUs at 100%... is that you ONLY have 8 cores! This means that running VB can bring the entire rest of your machine to a grinding halt if it needs/wants to. Same with memory... why give HALF your memory to VB if it's not required. As to the retina screen... esp if it's a 4K+ screen... for testing... try setting down the resolution and see if that makes a difference.